# Question on Outer Expectation unequal to Expectation of minimal measurable majorant

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation, weak-convergence

This is a problem given by Aad W. van der Vaart and Jon A. Wellner in their "weak convergence and stochastic process". It aims at constructing an example of "$E^{\ast}T$ is not always $ET^{\ast}$".

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be $\mathbb{R}$ with the $\sigma$-field generated by $[0,\infty)$ and the Borel sets in $(-\infty,0)$ and $P$ equal to the Cauchy measure. The map $T:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $T(\omega)=\omega$ has $E^{\ast}T=\infty$, but $ET^{\ast}$ does not exist.

Can someone help me to see why the statement is true?

For the definition of "Outer Expectation":

$E^{\ast}T=\inf\{EU:U\geq T,U:\Omega \rightarrow\bar{\mathbb{R}}\; \text{measurable and} \;EU \; \text{exists}  \}$.

For the definition of "Minimal Measurable majorant":

For any map $T:\Omega\rightarrow\bar{\mathbb{R}}$, there exists a measurable function $T^{\ast}:\Omega \rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ with (i) $T^{\ast}\geq T$; (ii) $T^{\ast}\leq U$ a.s., for every measurable $U:\Omega \rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ with $U\geq T$ a.s.

Comment: Do you believe people will go to VdVW, whatever these letters mean, and check the definitions you left out? I suggest to make the question self-contained AND to add your thoughts.

Comment: Thanks Did. I was in a hurry and now get things done better. Hope this fits well.

Answer (score 1):

(Standard) [Cauchy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution): (*definition*) Probability measure on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ with density $f$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure, where $f(x)=\frac1{\pi(1+x^2)}$ for every $x$ in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

$T^*$ is just $T$, since it's already measurable, and  $ET$ famously does not exist, so $ET^*$ does not exist.

But  $E^*T$ has to exist: it's an infimum over a set of expectations that exist. So that at least shows $ET^*\neq E^*T$.

Now consider a majorant $U$ of $T$ and think about the expectation of the positive and negative part of $U$. The expectation of the positive part is infinite, so if $EU$ exists the expectation of the negative part must be finite, so $EU=\infty$, and since $U$ was arbitrary, $E^*T=\infty$